# A well-defined distribution without a defined expected value.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X: \Omega \to S$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-valued random variable on the distribution $\mathbb{P}(X=(-1)^k \cdot k)= \frac{1}{k(k+1)}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{P}(X=(-1)^{k+1} \cdot k)=0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$. Prove that the distribution of $X$ is well-defined, but the expected value $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is not defined. I've worked out this proof:
Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then the distribution of $X$ is defined by $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}>0$ if there exists $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n=2x$, by $\frac{1}{|n|(|n|+1)}>0$ if there exists $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n=-(2x+1)$ and by $0$ else.

$$\mathbb{P}X(S)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k(k+1)}+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k(k+1)}$$
with the condition $\frac{k}{2} \in \mathbb{N}$ in the first summand and $\frac{k+1}{2} \in \mathbb{N}$ in the second summand, which yields
$$\mathbb{P}X(S)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \bigg(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\bigg)= 1 $$ and the distribution is well-defined, on the other hand:
$$\mathbb{E}[X]= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \cdot k \frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{1}{k+1}$$ which is the alternating harmonic series, which is not absolutely convergent, and thus the expected value is not defined. I am sure I'm missing important arguments and my proof looks really messy, any help cleaning it up or alternative answers would be appreciated!

Comment: Show that $\mathbb E[X\mathsf 1_{X>0}] = \mathbb E[X\mathsf 1_{X<0}] = +\infty$.